# Why do I get java.util.InputMismatchException?

Tags: java, boolean, java.util.scanner

```
//***************************************************************
//File: weight.java
//
//Purpose: Computes the ideal weight for both males and females.
//***************************************************************
import java.util.Scanner;

public class weight
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean answer1;
    System.out.println ("Are you a male (m) or female (f)?");
     boolean m=true;
    boolean f=false;
    answer1=scan.nextBoolean();

    int feet, inches;
    if (answer1=m)
    {
    System.out.println ("Enter your height in feet.  Inches will be asked later.");
    feet=scan.nextInt ();
    System.out.println ("Enter the remaining inches.");
    inches=scan.nextInt ();
    }
    if (answer1=f)
    System.out.println ("Enter your height in feet.  Inches will be asked later.");
    feet=scan.nextInt ();
    System.out.println ("Enter the remaining inches.");
    inches=scan.nextInt ();  
    }
    }
```

Full error:

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.nextBoolean(Unknown Source)
at weight.main(weight.java:17)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

I'm new to 'if' statements and booleans so if someone could explain that would be great!
Basically, I just want it to ask if the user is a male or a female and then relay certain code based on the answer.

Comment: what did you input for "Are you a male (m) or female (f)"?

Comment: opps you should input `true` of `false`. true for male. m is not a boolean right ??

Comment: I declared it though.                                                                                                  boolean m=true;
boolean f=false;                           Does this not work?

Comment: no .`nextBoolean` expect you to input a boolean true or false .when you input m it mismatch with a boolean.if you want to input m or f then use nextchar

Comment: It actually *isn't* a Compiler Error; it is just the case that the compiling service *runs the compiled code* ("Unknown Source") which generates a *Runtime Exception*. The compiling methods class 'JavaCompiler' appears on the stack as a side-effect even though the compilation has already successfully completed.

Answer (score 2):

Check the input for `answer1=scan.nextBoolean();` 
Only `true` or `false` is allowed as you use `nextBoolean()`.

By the way, you have 
`if (answer1=m)` and `if (answer1=f)` which is wrong. '`=`' is an ***assignment*** operator and '`==`' is the ***boolean*** operator.

`if (answer1 == m)` and `if (answer1 == f)` is right way to do and can help your problem.

You can consider to use char instead of the `boolean`, you can try it out as that makes sense when you ask a User to enter **Male** or **Female** but he has to enter `true` or `false` which he has no idea about.

Comment: @AusrichterSchlachtfeld  I have updated answer. Try to read input as Male or Female / M or F instead of boolean and mark the answer(by ticking it) if it solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the user to input 'm' or 'f' for the gender then taking `char` input is the best. Use it this way:

```
char answer1;
System.out.println ("Are you a male (m) or female (f)?");
answer1=scan.next().charAt(0);
```

And then for comparison don't use single `=` as that is assignment operator use `==` for comparison. Thus use it like this:

```
if (answer1=='m' || answer1=='M') //taking care of both capital or small input
```

or

```
if (answer1=='f' || answer1=='F')
```